# Is there any way to disable a row in a data table

Tags: lightning, datatable

I have a following data in a List,

From the following data I will create the native lightning datatable and it looks like follows

```
0: {Name: "Test Contact 2", Person__c: "a0j4E00000BY96GQAT"}
1: {Name: "Test Contact 1", Person__c: "a0j4E00000BY96GQAT"}
```

[image]

Afterwards I just selected the Contacts which I need to generate the Requests and when I click the Button the datatable will looks like below,

[image]

In the above datatable I'll need to disable the Test Contact 2 row to select because its status is Pending.

According to the above data I'll need to show those data in a datatable in a lightning component. What I need here is in that datatable I'll need to disable a particular row according to the record status__c field.

Is it possible in datatable? I couldn't find any place to refer it.

For a workaround I just hide the checkbox column if all records status are Pending and I used a Trigger to avoid creating the pending request again to a particular Contact and according to the results I did something to achieve what I need. But its very easy If we have a way to disable row wise.

Comment: Hi, if possible try conditional styling. which ever row has status value that's not supposed to be selected, grey-out the row by applying style from Javascript and disable the checkbox beside that row.

Comment: Does "disable" just mean not include row actions, here? Are you using the native `<lightning:dataTable>` component, and if so what does your markup look like? Could you [edit] your question to add some more details?

Comment: @DavidReed, Yes and also need to disable to check the checkbox, yes. I have edited.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to decide which button to disable for each row, you can handle it like this:

When you set your button column (oninit) set it's `disabled` attribute to a `fieldName`:

```
{label: 'myButton', fieldName: 'click', type: 'button', typeAttributes: {label:  'myButton',
                                                                        name: 'typeButton',
                                                                        disabled: {fieldName: 'typeButton_disabled'}}},
```

Then after you get your data, go over all rows and decide for each one what is the disabled status you want to give the button, and set the typeButton_disabled field accordingly:

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {

    if (you want to disable the button for this row) {
        data[i].typeButton_disabled = true;
    }
    else {
        data[i].typeButton_disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Now save your data to the attribute.